# Locally edit remote directories/files via ssh tunneling

Tags: ssh, sftp, ssh-tunnel, sshfs

As the title suggests I want to edit on my local machine (*Machine A*) files that are in a server (*Machine C*) that is accessible after sshing to another server (*Machine B*) (two hops in total).

I'm using Sublime Text 4 which has a package name SFTP, but I don't think it has the option of tunneling. I'm using Windows on the local computer (with WSL2 Ubuntu installed) and the remote server has Ubuntu.

I can use WinSCP to edit individual files in Sublime but I'm interested in accessing entire directories.

What would be the best way to achieve that?

**EDIT:** I have tried two approaches both of which are lacking.

**Approach 1:** Install rmate on remote server (*Machine C*) and rsub on the local computer (*Machine A*). I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42218611/4714146) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41931330/4714146). Sadly, this only enables me to edit individual files exactly like WinSCP.

**Approach 2:** Using sshfs. This way I mount the directory I want from the remote server (*Machine C*) to my local computer (*Machine A*). I used the following command.

```
sshfs username@MachineC:/path/to/remote/dir /path/to/local/dir -o ssh_command='ssh -J username@MachineB'
```

The problem with this approach lies with Sublime as it does not play well with mounted directories. It doesn't refresh when the files are changed and it needs a restart to register the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSH to forward any port from local to a remote machine and use a remote SSH host as "hop". SSH is able to forward ports, so you can use any application just by connecting to localhost (for example).

## SSH Remote Port Forwarding

Brings a port from a machine in the remote network to your machine:

```
ssh -N -R [your_ssh_server_interface]:[your_port]:[target-server]:[port_you_want_to_forward] [username]@[your_ssh_server_ip]
```

`your_ssh_server_interface`can be omitted when using localhost.

`-N` can be omitted, as it doesn't enable ssh command execution, it's there to be useful when forwarding ports.

This command is run at a remote machine (inside the target network).

### Example

```
ssh -N -R 192.168.67.1:4445:192.168.67.128:445 user@192.168.67.1
```

The above command forwards port 445 of host 192.168.67.128 IP 192.168.67.1 (through SSH).

The target-server, where you wille be able to connect to, can be set to 127.0.0.1.

For this to work, the SSHd on the remote machine hat to allow `GatewayPorts`- Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` fot this line:

```
GatewayPorts yes
```

Comment: I'm a little bit lost. Could you explain it given the following? Let's say that Machine A is the local machine, Machine B is the intermediate hop and Machine C is the end node that has the directory/files that I want to edit.